# Azure ioT and Stream Analytics job

Tags: azure, iot, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to collect data from a ioT device, as for now i am using this code to simulate the device. [remote_monitoring](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/device/samples/remote_monitoring.js). It send data and i can se the data in the dashboard. Next thing is that i want to save the data to a SQL database. I was thinking of using Stream Analytics to do the job. The problem i am having now is that when i select ioT HUB as a input i get the error

> Please check if the input source is configured correctly and data is in correct format.

I am trying to find documentation if there is something special i need to add to my JSON object before i send it.

Comment: Stream analytics is for *analyzing* the event stream, not pushing it to some other system. The Azure IoT Hub/Suite use Event Hub to ingest events, which can send the data to various consumers, including Azure SQL, Power BI, etc. You can find various examples in the Azure Event Hub documentation site

Comment: Alright, so i have to write a program in like node to lissen to all devices and so on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use Event Hub, update my post when i have a awnser.

Answer (score 1):

IoTHub is a supported input for Azure Stream Analytics and there is nothing wrong with using ASA as a "pump" to copy data from IoT Hub or Event Hubs to a store like SQL DB. Many use cases of ASA combine such "archiving" with other functions. The only thing to be careful with is the limited ingress rate of many ASA outputs, so SQL DB may not be able to keep up and throttle ASA in which case ASA may fall behind beyond the used hub's retention window, causing data loss.

Answer (score -1):

What about this doc https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs.md ? Does it help you?

Comment: Please don't just post a link. Make sure to provide some context about that link. For further information check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, especially the part "Provide context for links".